# Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

Tags: java, tcp, ice

When I run this programm it show this mistake.  Dose it because i donot run the service? How to writ config files for the following code?

```
com.zeroc.Ice.ObjectPrx obj = communicator.stringToProxy("IceStorm/TopicManager:tcp -p 10000");

com.zeroc.IceStorm.TopicManagerPrx topicManager = com.zeroc.IceStorm.TopicManagerPrx.checkedCast(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the IceStorm service to be able to connect to it, IceStorm/TopicManager is an object hosted by IceStorm service.

if you want to define the topic manager using a property you should use `communicator.propertyToProxy` instead of `communicator.stringToProxy` and define the proxy in the configuration file used to initialize the configuration.

```
com.zeroc.Ice.Communicator communicator = com.zeroc.Ice.Util.initialize(args, "config.sub", extraArgs);

com.zeroc.IceStorm.TopicManagerPrx manager = com.zeroc.IceStorm.TopicManagerPrx.uncheckedCast(
            communicator.propertyToProxy("TopicManager.Proxy"));
```

You should check IceStorm [clock demo](https://github.com/zeroc-ice/ice-demos/tree/3.7/java/IceStorm/clock).